# Rookie Assembly Bomb Defusal cmp Operator

Tags: c, assembly, cmp

I'm new to assembly and really have no idea what is going on.

I'm trying to complete a homework assignment in which we have to defuse a bomb by finding out the correct input to five phases of a program.

I've tried looking online for the answer to my question but I really have no idea what to search to find the answer I'm looking for.

I believe I understand everything in the code below from `<+0>` to `<+35>`. At `<+40>` the cmp operator is called to compare the `$0x2`, and what is stored in the `%eax` register. At the time of the comparison I believe `%eax` is still storing a function call to scanf (correct me if I'm wrong).

Through use of gdb I do know that the scanf function was called as follows: 
`scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);`

So what exactly is `$0x2` referring to in this case (is it just the value 2?) and what is happening when comparing the two items?

I believe this is GAS Syntax.

```
   0x0804870a <+0>:     sub    $0x2c,%esp
   0x0804870d <+3>:     lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048711 <+7>:     mov    %eax,0xc(%esp)
   0x08048715 <+11>:    lea    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x08048719 <+15>:    mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
   0x0804871d <+19>:    movl   $0x8048baa,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048725 <+27>:    mov    0x804b040,%eax
   0x0804872a <+32>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x0804872d <+35>:    call   0x8048480 <__isoc99_fscanf@plt>
   0x08048732 <+40>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x08048735 <+43>:    je     0x8048743 <phase_1_of_5+57>
   0x08048737 <+45>:    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
   0x0804873e <+52>:    call   0x80486ef <explode>
   0x08048743 <+57>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
   0x08048747 <+61>:    mov    %eax,%edx
   0x08048749 <+63>:    shl    $0x5,%edx
   0x0804874c <+66>:    add    %edx,%eax
   0x0804874e <+68>:    cmp    0x1c(%esp),%eax
   0x08048752 <+72>:    je     0x8048760 <phase_1_of_5+86>
   0x08048754 <+74>:    movl   $0x1,(%esp)
   0x0804875b <+81>:    call   0x80486ef <explode>
   0x08048760 <+86>:    add    $0x2c,%esp
   0x08048763 <+89>:    ret
```

Comment: The `cmp` subracts `0x2` (hexadecimal 2 == decimal 2) from the value of `%eax`, sets the flags accordingly, and leaves `%eax` unchanged.

Comment: Yes, `$2` is just `2`. It's comparing the return value of `fscanf`, meaning it's checking whether you entered 2 numbers. Don't get me wrong, but if you couldn't even solve this you will run into more trouble later and asking on SO is probably not the right approach.

Comment: Thanks guys. Appreciate the concern, Jester. I'm also very sure that I am going to run into more trouble. I am just having a hard time finding decent tutorials over assembly on the internet. I lost focus during an important lecture (curse you ADD) and now I'm a bit lost. I just spoke to my professor, but I forgot to ask about that line and didn't want to bother him again.

Comment: I think this is a very valid and good question for learning ASM. Not sure why the downvote. It covers using the stack, calling into api, and opcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common confusion with the JE and related instructions. I would recommend getting a debugger to visualize what the code is doing.

cmp is internally subtracting but really its checking if eax == 2.  If eax == 2 JE (JUMP IF EQUAL) it jumps so EIP register (the next instruction executed) becomes 0x08048743 (the memory address of "phase_1_of_5+57").  If eax != 2, it steps over JE ignoring it.

SPOILER DO NOT READ THIS UNTIL YOU PRACTISE YOURSELF AND GET STUCK AGAIN:

So we look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm. What fscanf does. We see that a return value of 2 means it expects 2 terms of input. Now we assume we enter two terms and now we follow the JE.

We see (this is why you need a debugger, to visualize this)

```
mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
...
cmp    0x1c(%esp),%eax

0x18 == 6th value on the stack
0x1c == 7th value on the stack
safe to assume these are the two input terms.

0x08048743 <+57>:    mov    0x18(%esp),%eax
0x08048747 <+61>:    mov    %eax,%edx
0x08048749 <+63>:    shl    $0x5,%edx
0x0804874c <+66>:    add    %edx,%eax
```

Here we can assume the way to defuse the bomb is to enter the left shift by 5 of the first term, added to the first term. To the second term.

So 0 0 should defuse it.

Comment: You don't need to "assume" as we can see their address being passed to `fscanf`.

Comment: 0 0 does defuse the bomb, but I am still slightly confused. I worked through the assembly on my own, and came to (I think) the same conclusion as you did, but I can't find any other input that works. I found that if the inputs are named x and y, then if x == y + (y*2^5) then the bomb should be defused, but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: Shifting by 5 bits and adding the original is just multiplication by 33. As such any pair where the second number is 33 times the first should work. Just checked, it does.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: I say assume because we don't know what fscanf does in this case with 100% certainty (as we do not have the bytecode), it could be redirected to do something else than expected, say via a hook or function body byte manipulation.